# PackageReferenec in ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, packagereference

I am trying to migrate an ASP.NET MVC 5 Website project from packages.config to use Package Reference. Our project uses .NET Framework 4.6.1. I have looked at the various articles online, but most of them are focused towards .NET Core projects.

I was able to use the migrate tool to make this switch, but now I am having issues (as expected due to non-support for these project types) with the nuget packages like JQuery with "Content" directories, and with Bootstrap with "ContentFiles" directories.

- How to get JQuery "Content" files to the output directory?
- How to get Bootstrap's "ContentFiles" copied to output directory?

If someone could point me to right resource, that would be great.

Comment: did you select the file - properties - copy to output as true

Comment: @Saravanan: There is no content directory in the csproj when PackageReference is used, if that's what you meant.

Comment: In this case, please use npm to manage these dependencies instead of using `nuget` so that you can easily manage `dev` and production level dependencies and also run `npm i` on the deployable artifact to get your scripts / css files